# Unity(C#) — Как проверить, прикреплен ли к объекту определенный скрипт?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть объект к которому прикреплен определенный скрипт, и есть другой объект со скриптом. Когда первый объект сталкивается с любым другим объектом, нужно проверить, есть ли у другого объекта тот скрипт, который прикреплен ко второму объекту. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
   if(col.gameObject.GetComponent<FirstScript>())
   {
       //do
   }
}
```